# iOS UIImageView how to add padding to rounded ImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `RoundImageView` which extends `UIImageView` with the following function to make it round:

```
-(void) makeImageViewRounded {
    //set the look of the image
    self.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    //self.layer.cornerRadius= self.frame.size.height /2;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
    self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
}
```

How can I create a margin between the border and the actual image (padding)? I want to expose the color that is set in `self.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];`

Answer (score 0):

Let `yourImageView` is 100*100 and padding = 10. Then resize your image to 80*80 and set this image.

And set `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property to `AspectFit`

Answer (score -2):

Create a UIView which is bigger than your UIImageView and has the Border.
Then Place your ImageView in Center of it.

Comment: its an alternative not a proper answer its mean making your view heavy it should be some property of uiimageview like in android there is padding left right top bottom option

Comment: There is no Padding in UIImageView. In iOS its the proper way to subclass anything to add custom behavior. In Android you have a completely different approach for layouting a View

Comment: no worries i have edited my image in photoshop gave the padding in image. yeah but when configuring dynamic solution we need to make custom class